# Facebook Share not working while logged in with Facebook Connect

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a Drupal 6 website where I've implemented Facebook Connect with the [JavaScript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) and it's been working fine for some months.

The site used the old Facebook Share button (pointing to sharer.php)  but that didn't work with the new Facebook Connect API so I replaced it with fb:share-button.

My problem is that the Facebook share button doesn't work for users logged in via Facebook Connect. The lightbox for Facebook Share appears empty with just the loading bars. If the user is logged in to the site as a non Facebook Connect user then Facebook share works normally.

I've searched for similar problems and found an unanswered post at Facebook developer forum that looks like a similar problem.

This site also uses Facebook Like buttons but those, as far as I know, don't allow including an image from the liked image like share does. The owner of the site needs Facebook Share and has no plans of removing it to work just with Facebook like.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got this code working for sharing

```
function share(){
         var share = {
             method: 'stream.share',
             u: document.getElementById('txtShare').value
         };

         FB.ui(share, function(response) { console.log(response); });
     }
```

Comment: I'm not sure how your code should be implemented, could you please add some more details? Thanks!